# CoffeeScript - "if item in list" equivalent

Tags: coffeescript

In CoffeeScript, I'm trying to test if a given string is a member of an array of strings. Here is what I have tried (note that the first attempt uses the `in` operator and the second one uses the `of` operator):

```
console.log list
list = [ i.courseid for i in list ]
console.log list
console.log courseid
console.log courseid in list
console.log '2904984' in list
console.log 2904984 in list
```

and:

```
console.log list
list = [ i.courseid for i in list ]
console.log list
console.log courseid
console.log courseid of list
console.log '2904984' of list
console.log 2904984 of list
```

The results of compiling and running both scripts is:

```
[ { courseid: '2904984', _id: 5243274d46f7f6d72e000001 },
  { courseid: '2484419', _id: 5245ac6ef3a459ee44000002 },
  { courseid: '2180094', _id: 5245b3fa659d2c2d45000001 },
  { courseid: '2179793', _id: 5245ca8ab405987a49000001 },
  { courseid: '2169240', _id: 5245ca8eb405987a49000002 } ]
2904984,2484419,2180094,2179793,2169240
2484419
false
false
false
```

Any clue as to why neither `item in list` or `item of list` returns `true` when the item is a member of the list?

Comment: Your list elements are objects, not strings nor numbers.

Comment: I would suggest not reinventing the wheel - http://underscorejs.org/#contains

Comment: @asawyer What do you mean by that comment?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to take a look at the generated JavaScript @jayhendren

Comment: @RobW I'll post the generated Javascript; I took a look at it; nothing seems obviously wrong.

Comment: @jayhendren UnderscopeJS has this functionality plus tons of other really useful stuff is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list = [i.courseid for i in list]` gives you a nested array of arrays (a 1-item array containing your array of string IDs). You want `list = (i.courseid for i in list)`, giving you a flat array of strings as you expect.

Comment: Thanks! My boss found this answer independently of you. I'm accepting it because it's the correct answer.

Comment: @jayhendren You might want to consider switching to a different version of Javascript for debugging. With Chrome, for example, you would have seen the second printout of `list` shown as `[Array[5]]` which would have given you an indication of your problem.

Comment: I agree. I'm not running this script in the browser though; I'm running it on the server-side using `Node.js`. It turns out that logging to the console in Node can be improved over the method that I used. The problem was immediately obvious when the array was logged to the console as JSON rather than as a string.